# PhantomJS.exe massive memory use with Webdriver

Tags: memory, webkit, automated-tests, phantomjs

I have written a simple scraping program using PhantomJS and webdriver, which essentially consists of the following steps:

Navigate to a page
Collect a number of links (30) from the page by xpath
For each link, navigate to that url and collect a bunch of text elements on the page

I am not calling this in JavaScript, I am using webdriver written in C#.

My issue is that the PhantomJS.exe process reaches memory usage of over 800 MB, which I can't understand why this is happening. My .net exe's memory usage (which calls the PhantomJS.exe) sticks around 12 MB throughout. I'm only using one instance, and running all processing in serial, so effectively one window or 'tab' as far as I am aware.

Has anybody come across similar issues using PhantomJS, any reason it should have this behaviour?

Comment: The same to me in PHP, trying to find a solution. Do you have any?

Comment: No sorry I didn't get to the bottom of this in the end, and ended up using a Selenium grid farm with chrome driver.